# Multiple Insertion Points wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Basically, I want to make something similar to "Split into lines" in sublime using wxWidgets. So say our textCtrl contains text

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
ffffff
```

what I want is when user selects all these lines and uses that feature (with everything highlighted - like Select All), he should get something like

```
aaaaaa|
bbbbbb|
cccccc|
dddddd|
```

Where `|` are the carets. So basically, I want to have multiple carets in one wxRichTextCtrl. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxRichTextCtrl` doesn't support this, but `wxStyledTextCtrl` does, see [Scintilla documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html).

Comment: I tried reading it but there's too much in it. Do you know few specific functions or the section in documentation which would help me understand it faster? Thanks!

Comment: I think you want `SetMultipleSelection()` and/or `SetAdditionalSelectionTyping()` (see the [corresponding messages](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETMULTIPLESELECTION)).